# Insufficient permissions for this file (I know it's old... but...)

Tags: google-drive-api

I think this is an old issue, but I still can't find any solution on Internet. Please kindly help me, very thanks.

Here is my case:

a. xxx@mycompany.com shares a folder to aaa@gmail.com

b. aaa@gmail.com upload a file(putty.bin) into this folder

That's all. And the only thing I need to do is "delete this file".
I need to say "I had already used service account to delete this file, but not work.".

Here is my python code:

```
import httplib2
import pprint
import sys

from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.client import SignedJwtAssertionCredentials

"""Email of the Service Account"""
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com'

"""Path to the Service Account's Private Key file"""
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH = 'xxxxxxxxxxx.p12'

def createDriveService(user_email):
    """Build and returns a Drive service object authorized with the service accounts
    that act on behalf of the given user.

    Args:
    user_email: The email of the user.
    Returns:
    Drive service object.
    """
    f = file(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH, 'rb')
    key = f.read()
    f.close()

    credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL, key, scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive', sub=user_email)
    http = httplib2.Http()
    http = credentials.authorize(http)

    return build('drive', 'v2', http=http)

drive_service = createDriveService('xxx@mycompany.com')

# List files
files = drive_service.files().list(
    q='trashed = false'
).execute()

target_file = None
for fitem in files['items']:
    if fitem['title'] == 'putty.bin':
        target_file = fitem
        break

print 'Delete %s' % target_file['id']
drive_service.files().delete(
    fileId=target_file['id']
).execute()
```

This python code can list files successfully (including putty.bin), but can not delete it, the error is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "quickstart.py", line 48, in <module>
    fileId=target_file['id']
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oauth2client-1.4.10-py2.7.egg/oauth2client/util.py", line 137, in positional_wrapper
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google_api_python_client-1.4.0-py2.7.egg/googleapiclient/http.py", line 729, in execute
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/1Bd2C2Xxcsls2anFfbVp2dsdtdSx? returned "Insufficient permissions for this file">
```

Does anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Did aaa@gmail.com remember to patch the permissions on the file they uploaded granting  xxx@mycompany.com access to the file?   By default when the file is uploaded its still owned by aaa@gmail.com, they have to patch the file with the permissions giving xxx@mycompany.com access.

Issue requst:  [Google drive api, upoad file with shared permissions](https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3717&q=API%3DDrive&sort=-stars&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20API%20Owner)

Comment: No. But when I login google drive with xxx@mycompany.com, I can delete this file by using Web UI. This needn't aaa@gmail.com to patch this file. Therefore, I think I also can do the same thing in this code, righit?

Comment: Who cant delete the file then the service account or xxx@mycompany.com  A service account isn't xxx@mycompany.com its xxxxxxxxxxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com.  It cant delete the file unless it has access.

Comment: xxxxxxxxxxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com is granted the permission from mycompany.com, so I can use it to list all files in xxx@mycompany.com's google drive. I also check the file permission, it show "xxx@mycompany.com can edit", and I actually can delete when I login as xxx@mycompany.com by webui. Only this code can't.

Comment: Would you mind just trying to grant xxxxxxxxxxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com access the file and then having the service account try and delete it.  xxxxxxxxxxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com is not xxx@mycompany.com

Comment: I login as aaa@gmail.com, and then grant 'xxxxxxxxxxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com' can edit this file. After this, I use the same code (service account of xxxxxxxxxxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com, and xxx@mycompany.com as user email), but still fail.

Comment: I find that is.. The service account of xxxxxxxxxxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com is granted by mycompany.com, so I can use this service account to impersonate anyone who belongs to mycompany.com. However, I can not impersonate aaa@gmail.com by this service account, because he doesn't belong to mycompany.com. Ok.. But~~~ Why does it work if I using Goolge Drive WebUI? I mean.. in this case, xxx@mycompany.com can delete the uploaded files which are uploaded by aaa@gmail.com. WHY?

Comment: Because service accounts are tricky, and annoying.  A service account is a user just like any other user you need to treat it as such.  Just because it was created by mycompany.com does not mean it has all the access that mycompany.com has.   You cant log into the web version of drive with the service account and test it.  So technically you dont know if it works on the drive webUI for the service account.   A service account is NOT my company.com its a sudo user.

Comment: how is aaa@gmail.com uploading the files?

Comment: Yes, you are right. But what shall I do to let my code can delete the uploaded files which are uploaded by aaa@gmail.com? Has anyway can do it? Google Drive WebUI can delete these files by using xxx@mycompany.com user, so I think I also can do the same thing in my code, right?

Comment: aaa@gmail.com login Google Drive UI and then upload files to the folder which is shared by xxx@mycompany.com. That's all.

Comment: Did you take xxxxxxxxxxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com  and give it access to the folder?

Comment: Yes, he does. xxxxxxxxxxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com can access that folder and also has edit permission for that folder and all of files under it.

Comment: Sorry, I find I am wrong. Even in Google Drive UI, xxx@mycompany.com can delete that file, but it still exists. This delete action only remove the share permission with xxx@mycompany.com, not really delete this file. Just looks like it is removed, but actually it's not. Thanks.